# How to make an autoupdating birthday list?

Tags: 2013, list

I have a birthday list with names, birthdays and so on..

How do I make the list updating itself when someone have birthday
in some upcoming days? it would be nice if it could display the news with f.ex. 2 days notice.

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more details. Like are you wanting to show the upcoming birthdays some where on your site? Or what is purpose of updating the list, like what should get updated and what should happen when update is complete.

Comment: Which information do you neet to autoupdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view where the `[BirthdayDate] >= [Today] and [BirthdayDate] <= [Today] + 2` This view will display only birthdays in the next 2 days (including today).

Or if you want only the ones exactly 2 days from now, `[BirthdayDate] = [Today] + 2`

Comment: Thanks Erin! I will try to edit the view tomorrow, and see if it works..